# The display property is not working with me in CSS

Tags: html, css, web

In CSS I have three buttons but by default, they are in the same line, so to make them on top of each other you should in the CSS selector of the container the property display and the value blocks like this `display: block;` but with me is not working, I don't know why. Look at the HTML:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background: linear-gradient(243.12deg, rgba(98, 98, 98, 0.88) 0.69%, #535050 48.82%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.88) 82.32%);;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

header{
    overflow: hidden;
}

img{
    height: 10%;
    width: 7%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;  
    overflow: hidden;
     
}

.nav-el-con{
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 45%;
}

.nav-btns{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 70px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}



.container > .btns{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css">
        <title>Play Questionera</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="navbar">
                <img src="/images/play_questionera.png" alt="play_questionera img">
                <div class="nav-el-con">
                    <button class="nav-btns"><a href="/home.html" class="nav-el" id="home">Home</a></button>
                    <button class="nav-btns"><a href="/download.html" class="nav-el" id="download">Download</a></button>
                    <button class="nav-btns"><a href="/contact.html" class="nav-el" id="contact">Contact</a></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="btns">
                <button class="algebra"><a href="/html/algebra-hardiness.html">Algebra</a></button>
                <button class="biology"><a href="/html/biology-hardiness.html">Biology</a></button>
                <button class="english-grammar"><a href="/html/english-grammar-hardiness.html">English Grammar</a></button>
            </div>

            <div class="descs">
                <p class="algebra-desc">
                    Algebra is the study of mathematical symbols and the rules for manipulating these symbols. 
                    It is a unifying thread of almost all of mathematics
                </p>
                <p class="biology-desc">
                    Biology is the natural science that studies life and living organisms, including their physical structure, 
                    chemical processes, molecular interactions, physiological mechanisms, development and evolution
                </p>
                <p class="english-grammar-desc">
                    English grammar is the way in which meanings are encoded into wordings in the English language. 
                    This includes the structure of words, phrases, clauses, sentences, and whole texts
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `.btns` selector I put in it the `display: block;` but it doesn't work

So please quick answer.

Comment: You selecting the wrong elements .btns is already a div which is a block element, apply `display:block` to the button like
`.btns > * { display: block}`

Comment: `.container > .btns > button { ... `  is the selector for all buttons inside `btns` div

Comment: So what you mean I should put the property in the button itself, not in the container of the buttons ??

Comment: yes apply display block to buttons itself

Answer (score 1):

You are using your css on .container > .btns, but u want to use ur css on .container > .btns > button ..

I used ur code below to show u..

```css
.container > .btns > button {
  display: block;
  
  margin: 10px 0; // Optional just for spacing vertically
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="btns">
        <button class="algebra"><a href="/html/algebra-hardiness.html">Algebra</a></button>
        <button class="biology"><a href="/html/biology-hardiness.html">Biology</a></button>
        <button class="english-grammar"><a href="/html/english-grammar-hardiness.html">English Grammar</a></button>
    </div>

    <div class="descs">
        <p class="algebra-desc">
            Algebra is the study of mathematical symbols and the rules for manipulating these symbols. 
            It is a unifying thread of almost all of mathematics
        </p>
        <p class="biology-desc">
            Biology is the natural science that studies life and living organisms, including their physical structure, 
            chemical processes, molecular interactions, physiological mechanisms, development and evolution
        </p>
        <p class="english-grammar-desc">
            English grammar is the way in which meanings are encoded into wordings in the English language. 
            This includes the structure of words, phrases, clauses, sentences, and whole texts
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this markup:

```
<div class="button-group">
  <button class="button algebra"><a href="/algebra/">Algebra</a></button>
  <button class="button biology"><a href="/biology/">Biology</a></button>
  <button class="button english-grammar"><a href="/english-grammar/">English Grammar</a></button>
</div>
```

This CSS:

```
.button {
  display: block;
}
```

will give each of your `<button>` elements a `display` value of `block`.